# IT Security Stack Exchange moderator cards

Tags: discussion

We recently printed some business cards for our Stack Exchange employees and they turned out great.

It got us thinking: our sites' moderators have been working hard to keep our sites high quality for the past few years. They may not be employees, per se, but great community moderators are why our communities are safe, sane, and worth visiting in the first place..

If you're a moderator, would you be interested in having your own IT Security Stack Exchange contact card? Would you find it useful?

I can see them being handy to pass out during your local meetups or conferences. Or, simply hand them out to your co-workers.

Below is a mockup:

<sub>(click on image to see full res version)</sub>

[image: IT Security Stack Exchange Moderator Cards]

Of course Twitter ID/phone# are optional. It can be Skype, AIM, URL etc.

Note: the text rendering in the mockup is slightly blurry. But when printed it will be crisp.

Comment: What about the inverse? If I'm interested, can I be a moderator? :) Seriously, those are slick for promotion.

Comment: They look amazing IRL. The card stock they use is very good quality.

Comment: I absolutely agree with @RoryAlsop - the cards are beautiful (almost don't want to give them out! ;) ). As far as moderators go, it seems that 2 out of 3 already have them... :D

Comment: @JeffFerland I plan to create generic site cards for non-mod users who want them to promote the site. They will sport simliar design.

Comment: @Jin - Nice work!  What kind of stock / ink do you use?  A friend of mine does branding for a living and I think she'll appreciate your eye

Comment: @makerofthings we use moo.com for our cards. So far we're very impressed by the quality and excellent customer service.

Comment: @Jin So I'm a mod now. How 'bout them cards? :)

Comment: @JeffFerland grats! we'll email you the form to fill out shortly.

Answer (score 3):

OK, the cards are now available -- all current moderators were mailed a link to the form to customize the cards. Enjoy!